# scan for all wifi devices not just hotspots (Android)

Tags: android, wifi, device

Does anybody have an android code for how to scan for wifi devices (not just hotspot) like phones, tablets etc..? I tried "sniffer","promiscuous", even monitor in android developer and i didn't find anything, i only got the one for the access point through wifiManager.

Thanks